# How to get all values of a specific column based on a specific value in another column in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

My format for CSV files are

Camp.CSV

```
Campaign,AdGroup,Keyword,Status
florida,orlando,floridaorlando,Paused
new york,albany,new yorkalbany,Active
```

geo_fl.csv

```
Campaign,Adgroup
florida,orlando
florida,miami
new york,new york
california,san francisco,
california,los angeles
```

I want to list all the Adgroup in 'geo_fl.csv' based on 'Campaign' in 'Camp.csv' like for 
florida in 'Camp.csv' it should return the values (orlando,miami) in 'geo_fl.csv'

So far code is as follows -

```
 # Declare function to check with the presence of the 'campaignname' or not
 campaignname <- function(point1, point2) {
 conditioncheck <- any(point2==point1)
 }
# Declare a function to check the presence of the 'adgroupname' or not

# Read the CSV files for reference
newlistings <- read.csv("/home/chi/Downloads/Camp.csv",header=TRUE)
georeportrecord <- read.csv("/home/chi/Downloads/geo_fl.csv",header=TRUE)
# Store the data of each column in a variable for 'Camp.csv'
Keyword <- newlistings$keyword
campaign <- newlistings$Campaign
adgroup <- newlistings$AdGroup
status <- newlistings$Status
# Store the data of each column in a variable for 'geo_fl.csv'
geoCampaign <- georeportrecord$Campaign
geoAdGroup <- georeportrecord$Adgroup

# getting the values for 'number of rows' in each CSV list
nCGM <- nrow(newlistings)
nAdwords <- nrow(georeportrecord)

Pts2 <- georeportrecord[,c("Campaign")]
CGMGeoList <- NULL
# checking for the presence of the element in the vector
#for(i in campaign){
for(i in 1:nCGM){
Pts1 <- NULL
Pts1$Campaign <- (newlistings$Campaign[i])
# passing the value to the function for 'campaign' presence check
checkcondition <- campaignname(Pts1,Pts2)
if(checkcondition == TRUE){
   ad <- geoAdgroup[which(geoCampaign==i)# Stuck here(returning no result)
 }
 }
```

Also I have tried

```
for(i in campaign)
 { if (any(geoCampaign==i) == TRUE){
print(i)
# But also I want to list all adgroup for 'geo_fl.csv' together.
```

}
   }

My desired output

```
 Campaign,AdGroup,Keyword,Status,Campaignpresentingeo_fl,Adgrouppresentingeo_fl
 florida,orlando,floridaorlando,Paused,YES,YES
 new york,albany,new yorkalbany,Active,YES,NO
```

Condition for the above desired result

```
 for(i in campaign){
 If(( i present in georeportrecord)==TRUE))#for that particular 'campaign' in 'Camp.csv' check the condition for 'Adgroup' in 'geo_fl.csv'
{ If ((AdGroup[i] present in georeportrecord$Adgroup)==TRUE))#AdGroup for that particular 'campaign' 'i' in 'Camp.csv' is also present as an adgroup in 'geo_fl.csv'
{
output write.csv(florida,orlando,floridaorlando,Paused,YES,YES)
}else{
write.csv(florida,orlando,floridaorlando,Paused,YES,NO)
}
}else{write.csv(florida,orlando,floridaorlando,Paused,NO,NO)
}
```

Output the data onto a CSV file , just 2 additional columns in Camp.csv which indicates YES and NO 
How to list the values as specified above so that 
I can write to another CSV file, Please help me with the following, new to R, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `merge(newlistings, georeportrecord, by="Campaign")` give you what you want? Also, for the purposes of your question, it doesn't matter that the data started in CSV files; once read into R, the data is in `data.frame`s.

Comment: @BrianDiggs : the if condition is not getting checked. I do not understand why?Let me try with that in a basic way.

Comment: You're looking for `match()`.  You'll do well to make your questions MUCH shorter and more concise. This question could easily be posed in less than 10 lines.

Comment: @geotheory : Actually new to R so that's why specified in details

Comment: I mean to offer advice not criticism. You're much more likely to get a quick, helpful response (and avoid the wrath of the mark-down enthusiasts) if your question is short and focussed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After required output,

```
x<-read.csv(text='Campaign,Adgroup
florida,orlando
florida,miami
new york,new york
california,san francisco
california,los angeles', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)


y=read.csv(text="Campaign,AdGroup,Keyword,Status
florida,orlando,floridaorlando,Paused
new york,albany,new yorkalbany,Active", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

Campaigns<-x$Campaign
AdGroups<-interaction(x$Campaign, x$Adgroup)

y$campaignpresence<-ifelse(y$Campaign %in% Campaigns,"YES", "NO")
y$geopresence<-ifelse(interaction(y$Campaign, y$AdGroup) %in% AdGroups,"YES", "NO")
```

output

```
 y
  Campaign AdGroup        Keyword Status campaignpresence geopresence
1  florida orlando floridaorlando Paused              YES         YES
2 new york  albany new yorkalbany Active              YES          NO
```

ignore below, as it answered separate thing

another approach with data.table. I even don't see the need of first table `camp.csv` provided that you have all your unique campaigns in second table. I just made dummmy data here where `x` is your `campaign` and `y` is your `Adgroup`

```
require(data.table)
x<-data.frame(x=sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), y=sample(100:999,100))
y<-data.table(x)
l<-y[,list(y=list(y)),by=x]
l$y<-sapply(l$y, paste, collapse=",")
write.table(l,...)
```

Be careful with writing as csv because your second column now has comma in it, so tsv may be better

Comment: Hi, the `y` column here is a `list` (the `,` is pretty display). You can't use `write.table` with list columns.. I think you'll have to `paste`.

Comment: @Ananta : Modified my question to the required output.

Comment: @Arun : Thanks for the suggestion. I have modified my question to the required output. Thanks in advance for further help.

Comment: @Ananta : So it means that for each entry it will check the Campaign first and then the Adgroup for that particular campaign as specified in the question?

Comment: @Ananta : Thanks, worked like a gem. Thanks to StackOverflow we can interact with good programmers.

Comment: @Arun : Still I am slightly confused. Check with my comment above.Thanks.

Comment: @user3188390 yes, I used the interaction to simplify the checking Campaign first and Adgroup. It just checks whether combination of those two was there

Comment: @Ananta : So if Campaign is there and but AdGroup is not there, what will happen then?

Comment: @Ananta : I did check with few examples, it seems so that it is first checking Campaign and if Campaign matches then it checks the Adgroup, is that true for the solution provided?

Comment: @user3188390, the solution works as you wanted because for Adgroup it checks combination (although not exactly checking in order), and for Campaign, it just checks campaign

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want your output to look like, but here's a simple way to concatenate all levels of one factor that belonging to each of the levels of another factor:

```
georeportrecord <- read.csv(text='Campaign,Adgroup
florida,orlando
florida,miami
new york,new york
california,san francisco
california,los angeles', header=TRUE)

newlistings <- read.csv(text='Campaign,AdGroup,Keyword,Status
florida,orlando,floridaorlando,Paused
new york,albany,new yorkalbany,Active', header=TRUE)

out <- aggregate(subset(georeportrecord, 
                        Campaign %in% newlistings$Campaign)$Adgroup, 
                 list(Campaign=subset(georeportrecord, 
                      Campaign %in% newlistings$Campaign)$Campaign), 
                 paste0)

out

  Campaign              x
1  florida orlando, miami
2 new york       new york
```

Use `write.csv` to write the data out to a csv (see `?write.csv`).

**EDIT:** (After clarification of desired output)

The above code returns a concatenated string containing the Adgroups present in each Campaign that exists in `newlistings`. To present as requested by the OP:

```
newlistings$Campaignpresentingeo_fl <- 
  newlistings$Campaign %in% georeportrecord$Campaign

newlistings$Adgrouppresentingeo_fl <- 
  apply(newlistings, 1, function(x) x[2] %in% 
          subset(georeportrecord, Campaign==x[1])[, 'Adgroup'])
```

Comment: I want to check for the presence of florida in 'Camp.csv' in 'geo_fl.csv' and then list all the Adgroup for florida in 'geo_fl.csv'

Comment: I have modified the question for my required output.Thanks for the help, please help me get the answer.

Comment: @user3188390: I've edited the answer so that only Campaigns that exist in `newlistings` are considered.

Comment: I got to the point as explained above, but as I have kind of specified the required output, to check with the fact that if campaign in newlistings is present in georeportrecord or not, if yes then Write to csv file as YES, otherwise NO, and then if the campaign is present, to check whether for that particular campaign the adgroup in newlistings is present or not in georeportrecord, if present YES, otherwise NO.

Comment: Again I appreciate your help. I have specified the condition in the question and what I am desiring for.

Comment: Checked the other answer for reference, got the right output, thanks for the help again.